# Regarding invertible functions being outer

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hardy-spaces

I am reading these notes titled [Hardy spaces, inner and outer functions, shift-invariant
subspaces, Toeplitz and Hankel operators](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~pmt6jrp/yorkleeds.pdf)

In the second last paragraph, it says that any function that is invertible in $H^\infty$ is outer.  Can anyone tell how such a function is outer?

Answer (score 1):

If $f\in H^{\infty}$ is invertible in $H^{\infty}$ with inverse $g\in H^{\infty}$, then
$$
        1 = |f||g| \implies \ln|f|=-\ln|g| \mbox{ in } \mathbb{D}.
$$
Therefore $\ln|f|$ is absolutely integrable because $\ln^{+}|f|$ and $\ln^{-}|f|$ are both integrable.